# How to get more seed packets to complete 40 seed packets quest?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

In plants vs zombies 2 there are quest that tell me to get 40 seed packets.

I did events, I did 3 pinata, I did arena.

I usually have 33 out of 40 seed packets.

I wonder if there should be anything infinitely repeatable where I can get those seed packets? So I can get 40

Answer (score 1):

The game's choices have expanded a lot since you asked this, but I figured it might be useful for someone.

Note that I've posted this assuming you're looking for Freeplay options, so these are your choices if you're looking for something that won't cost you anything (even coins):

1. Collect level pinatas - Every 12 hours you can earn 3 pinatas by playing the standard levels and these will generally have between 6-8 world plants in them. Assuming you do one round of these per day, you'll average about 20 packets right there.
2. Play the daily pinata party - Winning this will usually get you about 6+ packets for free.
3. Play the Arena - You get a freeplay every 4 hours and you get a bunch of packets when your win streak reaches 3, 5, and 7.
4. Daily Gift - The shop has a daily gift that gives you 10 packets.
5. Play Penny's Pursuit - Each of the levels has a certain difficulty where they'll award packets for the first time you win them. Furthermore, once you fill the meter, you can fight Dr. Zomboss who always awards packets on a win (between 20 and 40 depending on difficulty).
6. Complete Weekly/Monthly Events - There's a bunch of various events that roll through featuring a series of levels to test drive a plant they're trying to roll out. Completing these levels often gives you a bunch of packets (usually 50).